# Is there any way to import data from excel sheet to dhtmlspreadsheet?

Tags: dhtmlx

dhtmlxSpreadsheet does not option of importing data from excel sheet. Is there any way we can achieve it ?

Comment: please try google and grammar correct

Answer (score 0):

dhtmlxSpreadsheet has PHP API that can be used for loading the data to Spreadsheet. To read the data from Excel, you can use PHPExcel library. Alternative solution - just copy/past the data to dhtmlxSpreadsheet via Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V.